# How can I use variables on a variables loaded from text file?

Tags: python

Sorry for the confusing title, I haven't got the idea how to phrase the question better. Consider this text file:

sampleText.txt

```
Hi, my name is + Name
```

when I load the text using `msg = open(r'sampleText.txt', 'r')` and set a `Name = 'John'` variables, the `Name` inside sampleText.txt is ignored and the file was printed as-is.

The desired behavior is

```
Name = 'John'
msg = 'Hi, my name is ' + Name
print(msg)
```

which will print `Hi, my name is John`, I want to be able to load the `msg =` from a text file.

Sorry for the confusing question, thank you.

Comment: `msg.replace('+ Name', Name)`…?!

Comment: I'd suggest using another syntax, but basically what you want ot do is called "templating", using a "template text" that has some placeholders (your "variables") that you want to fill. I can see several problems using the `+` syntax, that could be avoidable with another syntax. It may look a bit complex at first, but here is the builtin templating system from Python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings

Comment: Template seems to be what I'm looking for. Thank you!